# How do I append text to the start, middle, and end of each line from one file to another using python3?

Tags: html, python-3.x, text, append

I am writing a script to change the formatting of the text from one file, and create a new text file with the changes in formatting.
I have been able to remove unwanted characters, but haven't found a way to append text to the beginning of every line in the file.

Content from the original file looks like:

```
DMA 123 USA 12345
```

What I need it to look like after appending data to the start, middle, and end of the string:

```
<option label="DMA 123 USA" value="123"></option>
```

I have almost 100 lines that vary some, but follow the above formatting. I am trying to automate this as it will be a frequent task to adjust the original file to the new format for web publishing

I have been searching and haven't found any way to do it yet. Here is my current code:

```
path = 'file.txt'
tvfile = open(path,'r')
days = tvfile.read()

new_path = 'tvs.txt'
new_days = open(new_path,'w')

replace_me = ['-' ,'(' ,')' ,',' , '"' , ]
for item in replace_me:
days = days.replace(item,'')
days = days.strip()

new_days.write(days)
print(days)

tvfile.close()
new_days.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Nit: you need to prepend, not append. That said, try something along these lines:

```
buffer = ""
for item in replace_me:
    line = "<option label=\""
    line = line + days.replace(item,'').strip()
    line = line + "\"></option>"
    buffer = buffer + line

new_days.write(buffer)
```

Comment: Looks like I was editing my question as you were responding. I added your corrections. The code executes, but only seems to edit the first line, not each of them